# How to use eager loading throughout Auth()?

Tags: laravel

`UserModel` has a relation to a `Doctor`:

```
public function doctor() {}
```

The next way is working:

```
Auth::user()->doctor->name
```

How to use eager loading like this:

```
Auth::user::with('doctor')->name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually return the result(s) of calling your relationship:

```
$doctor = Auth::user::with('doctor')->first();

dd($doctor->name);
```